# Python package structure supporting * imports

Tags: python, package, project, python-import

I'm restructuring a python project that evolved from a small set of scripts in something bigger. I didn't think about a proper package structure before so all the scripts live in package root dir.

I'm trying to give the project a the proper "package" structure like this:

```
packagename/
    docs/
    packagename/
        __init__.py
        module_data.py
        module_corrections.py
        module_plot.py
        subpackage1/
        subpackage2/
    README.md
```

I want to support importing the package as:

```
from packagename import *
```

The effect of the previous import should be loading a few submodules or subpackages, but also some class and function that I would like to provide without prepending the module name.

Using `__all__` in `__init__.py` I can only load submodules or subpackages.

How can I load, for example a `Data()` class from `module_data` and a function `dplot` from module `module_plot`?

Furthermore, how can I import `module_data` with another short name (e.g. `mda`)?

**EDIT**

## Short Answer

All the names I want to provide must be imported or defined in `__init__.py` **and**
added as string to the list `__all__`.

Thanks to @FMc for providing an example and insight.

Comment: FYI `from foo import *` is generally bad practice - see [PEP-008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Comment: When a program uses a package I agree. But when running interactive session I want to be able to save the extra typing: "practicality beats purity".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example -- but, as a general rule, you shouldn't use wildcard imports (only under narrowly defined circumstances, and only if you define `__all__`).

```
# Directory structure.
.
├── foopack/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── data.py
│   └── plot.py
└── run.py

# foopack/data.py
class Data(object):
    def blah(self):
        print self.x

# foopack/plot.py
def dplot():
    print 'dplot()'

# foopack/__init__.py
# Here we use relative imports and define __all__.
from .data import Data
from .plot import dplot    
__all__ = 'Data dplot'.split()

# A demo script: demo.py
from foopack import *

d = Data()
d.x = 32
d.blah()
dplot()
```

Comment: What is the difference between `from .data import Data` and `from data import Data`?

Comment: Answering my own question: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references